# Como criar um tabuleiro de tamanho determinado pelo usuário e apresentá-lo como texto usando python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou tentando criar um programa em Python 3.6.1 que cria um tabuleiro de acordo com o tamanho digitado pelo usuário final e imprime o resultado no shell.

Ele precisa ser apresentado como texto, e não pode utilizar nenhuma biblioteca.
Por mais que a biblioteca seja interna.

Exemplo: se o usuário digitar um tabuleiro com 10 linhas e 15 colunas. O programa  teria que gerar esse tabuleiro 10x15. Sendo que todos os valores dele devem ser células preenchidas por strings. Porque, posteriormente, ao usuário inserir o valor "P", por exemplo, ele irá alterar uma célula pré-definida por mim.
Em seguida o tabuleiro seria impresso novamente com o valor da célula pré-definida anteriormente por mim.

EX:
O usuário insere as informações iniciais:

insira a quantidade de linhas: 10

insira a quantidade de colunas: 15

o tabuleiro inicialmente seria assim:

```
  0123456789.....
0 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
3 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
4 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
5 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
6 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
7 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
8 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
9 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Em seguida, o usuário iria inserir P nas coordenadas 3x3, por exemplo:

insira o que deseja na linha 3 coluna 3: P <<<< usuário digitou P

Após isso, o tabuleiro seria impresso novamente, com o seguinte resultado:

```
 

   0123456789.....
 0 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 1 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 2 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 3 XXXPXXXXXXXXXXX #o P seria inserido nessa linha. Exatamente onde foi mandado.
 4 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 5 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 6 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 7 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 8 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 9 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Alguém sabe me dizer como fazer isso?

A parte das perguntas ao usuário, eu sei como fazer.

Meu problema é com o tabuleiro. Não faço nem idéia de como deixar como falei.
Criar uma matriz seria uma boa solução? Ou existe uma forma menos complicada?
já tentei de várias formas gerar esse tabuleiro, mas, sem sucesso.

Não sei se estou errando na lógica ou na sintaxe, pois comecei a programar com python há pouco tempo.

pesquisei bastante sobre uma possível solução, mas não encontrei informações claras.

Eu tenho mais experiência com php atualmente.

Toda ajuda é bem-vinda.

Desde já, obrigado.

PS: O resultado mais próximo do que preciso que consegui fazer foi esse:

```
linhas = int(input('insira a quantidade de linhas:'))
colunas = int(input('insira a quantidade de colunas:'))
celula = "X"

for a in range(linhas):
    print(celula*colunas)
```

Ele gera tudo aparentemente como preciso.
Mas não é bem assim que o resultado final deveria ficar.
Eu preciso que cada X impresso na tela seja um "espaço" dinâmico, onde cada um pode ser alterado posteriormente com qualquer outro valor de acordo com as coordenadas. Ex: F na linha 4 coluna 7 .
Não estou sabendo fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda, comentei o código para te dar uma noção do que está acontecendo.

Minha sugestão é que vá rodando parte a parte para entender o funcionamento

**Código:**

```
#pergunta a qtd de linhas e colunas para o usuario
lins = int(input("Insira o num de linhas: "))
cols = int(input("Insira o num de colunas: "))

#cria uma lista com o "X" aparecendo tantas vezes quando o nºde colunas
table = []
for i in range(lins):
    table.append(list('X'*cols))

#une as listas sem nenhum espaco para mostrar na tela
for line in table:
    print(''.join(line))

#pergunta qual linha e coluna deseja alterar
lin_alterar = int(input("Qual linha deseja alterar?: "))
col_alterar = int(input("Qual coluna deseja alterar?: "))

#qual o valor novo a ser inserido
vlr_novo = 'P'

#altera o item da posicao escolhida para o vlr_novo
table[lin_alterar - 1][col_alterar - 1] = vlr_novo

#une as listas sem nenhum espaco para mostrar na tela
for line in table:
    print(''.join(line))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> Insira o num de linhas: 5
>>> Insira o num de colunas: 10
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
>>> Qual linha deseja alterar?: 3
>>> Qual coluna deseja alterar?: 2
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
>>> XPXXXXXXXX
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
>>> XXXXXXXXXX
```

Na essência, sua tabela padrão nesse exemplo tem o seguinte formato:

```
[['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']]
```

Ela é uma lista contendo M listas com N itens, onde:

- M = nº linhas
- N = nº colunas

Answer (score 1):

O que fiz foi algo mais complexo, e com algumas coisas desnecessárias, mas que obtém o mesmo resultado.

Por conta dos espaços, o tabuleiro só poderá ter 56 colunas (acho que pode aumentar essa quantia se o monitor for maior, senão fica tudo bugado).

Coloquei espaços por que após chegar na 10ª coluna e adiante não tem como por "10" em cima de um único "X"

```
linhas = int(input('Quantas linhas? : '))
colunas = int(input('Quantas colunas? : '))

print('\n    |  ',end='')
for i in range(0,colunas):
        if i > 9:
                print(str(i)+' ', end='') #Retirei um espaço para que a posição dos numeros não fique errada
        else:
                print(str(i)+'  ', end='')
#print('|','\n   |'+'-'*3+'-'*((colunas*3)-1)+'|') #Um traço que entre os numeros da coluna
print('|')
for i in range(0,linhas):
        if i >= 10 and i < 100:
                print(i,' |'+'  X'*colunas,' |') #Linhas maiores que 9 e menores que 100 (10-99)
        elif i >= 100:
                print(i,'|'+'  X'*colunas,' |') #Linhas maiores que 9 e menores que 100 (10-99)
        else:
                print(i,'  |'+'  X'*colunas,' |') #Linhas menores que 10

while 1:
        local_c = int(input('\nQual local da coluna? : '))
        if local_c > colunas-1:
                print('local inválido.\n')
                continue
        break

while 1:
        local_l = int(input('Qual local da linha? : '))
        if local_l > linhas-1:
                print('local inválido.\n')
                continue
        break

print('\n    |  ',end='')
for i in range(0,colunas): #Numeros da coluna
        if i > 9:
                print(str(i)+' ', end='') #end='' serve para impedir a quebra de linha "\n"
        else:
                print(str(i)+'  ', end='')
print('|')
for i in range(0,linhas):
        if i == local_l: #Linha que será alterada
                c1 = local_c
                c2 = (colunas-c1)-1
                if i > 9 and i < 100:
                        print(str(i),' |'+'  X'*c1,' P'+'  X'*c2,' |') #Linhas maiores que 9 e menores que 100 (10-99)
                elif i >= 100:
                        print(str(i),'|'+'  X'*c1,' P'+'  X'*c2,' |') #Linhas maiores que 9 e menores que 100 (10-99)
                else:
                        print(i,'  |'+'  X'*c1,' P'+'  X'*c2,' |') #Linhas menores que 10
        elif i >= 10 and i < 100:
                print(i,' |'+'  X'*colunas,' |') #Linhas maiores que 9 e menores que 100 (10-99)
        elif i >= 100:
                print(i,'|'+'  X'*colunas,' |') #Linhas maiores que 99
        else:
                print(str(i),'  |'+'  X'*colunas,' |') #Linhas menores que 10
```

**saída:**

```
>>> Quantas linhas? : 10
>>> Quantas colunas? : 10
>>> 
>>>     |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  |
>>> 0   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 1   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 2   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 3   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 4   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 5   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 6   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 7   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 8   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 9   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 
>>> Qual local da coluna? : 5
>>> Qual local da linha? : 5
>>> 
>>>     |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  |
>>> 0   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 1   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 2   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 3   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 4   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 5   |  X  X  X  X  X  P  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 6   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 7   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 8   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
>>> 9   |  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  |
```

Espero que eu tenha te ajudado, se quiser, posso simplificar o código.